# Sync data of external server and firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, polymer-2.x

My polymer file is running on server "A" whose work is to bring and send data to that private server "A". All data of this private server I can fetch through polymer so I am sending data to firebase. My problem is I want to notify polymer, If there is any update in firebase so that I can send data back to private server.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Now I have data from Private server to firebase using polymer.js but i want to implement this part => (to bring data from firebase to private server whenever new data arrives in firebase )

Comment: How I should move forward !!!!